# CSS need to overlay element on a inline style iframe with { position: fixed !important; z-index: 2147483647 !important}

Tags: css, powerbi-embedded

I am working on a power BI embed where which can be clicked to make it full screen. It will launch up an Iframe which will have inline styles. and get defined as follows:

[image]

Furthermore I have my own  element which I want to render on top of it. The code is as follows:

```
<div onclick="console.log('test')" ng-if="vm.openWidget === vm.wid" style="position: fixed !important; bottom: 50px; right: 50px; height: 50px; width: 200px; background: red; z-index: 99999999999">

    <div style="color: white;" ng-click="vm.exitFullScreen()" >
        ICON TO CLICK
    </div>
    test {{ vm.wid }}
</div>
```

[image]

I am using AngularJs 1.5 as a front-end framework. I shows the  But the clicks are being overlaid by the power bi embed. Once I close the embed I can click the div and it will work.

However I want to let it work on top of the power embed overlay.

For completeness I have included the html code below:

```
<div ng-show="vm.loadingContent" class="loader"></div>




<div ng-show="!vm.loadingContent">
    <!--child: {{ vm.childReport }}-->



    <!-- When the widget hasn't been configured. -->
    <div ng-if="vm.powerbiNotConfigured != ''">
        {{ vm.powerbiNotConfigured }}
    </div>

    <!-- when the widget is configured. -->
    <section>
        <div>
            <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--FullScreen" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="vm.showFullScreen(e)"></i>
        </div>


        <div class="row" ng-show="vm.powerbiNotConfigured == '' && vm.viewType == 'dashboard'">
            <ul class="breadcrumb" style="margin-left: -5px; margin-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0;">
                <li><a role="button" ng-click="vm.backToDashboard()" href="javascript:void(0)">{{::vm.dashboardName}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <section style="position: relative;">
            <div class="embedContainer powerbIContainer" ng-class="{ 'powerbiDashboard' : vm.powerbiNotConfigured == ''}" ng-style="vm.widgetHeight" style="z-index: 300 !important"></div>

        </section>

    </section>



</div>


<div onclick="console.log('test')" ng-if="vm.openWidget === vm.wid" style="position: fixed !important; bottom: 50px; right: 50px; height: 50px; width: 200px; background: red; z-index: 99999999999">

    <div style="color: white;" ng-click="vm.exitFullScreen()" >
        ICON TO CLICK
    </div>
    test {{ vm.wid }}
</div>
```

Comment: Well 2147483647 sounds pretty max-int-ish, so the browser probably won’t let you go any higher. I would try and [overwrite the inline styles](https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/) for the iframe with a lower z-index value to start.

Comment: That's what I thought to, however I cannot access the iframe's content since it's coming from a different domain,

Comment: Who said anything about accessing the iframe’s content? The `iframe` element itself is part of your document, and therefor can be affected by your stylesheet.

Comment: Where is your widget code in relation to the iframe code?  You don't need to beat the iframe's z-index - just it's ancestor that is in the same stacking context: https://jsfiddle.net/u0j9ks7k/ In this fiddle, you see the top test as the widget card, test1 as the ancestor in the same stacking context and inner as the iframe.  If you can't do this - just give the thing you want to click through `pointer-events:none`

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen on clicks on a dashboard(it looks like you are embedding a dashboard) you can set a listener on tile clicked event, that way the iframe will not swallow your clicks. also you get data from the event that will help you embed the tile in full screen(embedUrl, tileId...). here is an example from the live sample (https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html)

```
// Get a reference to the embedded dashboard HTML element
var dashboardContainer = $('#dashboardContainer')[0];

// Get a reference to the embedded dashboard.
dashboard = powerbi.get(dashboardContainer);

// dashboard.off removes a given event listener if it exists.
dashboard.off("tileClicked");

// dashboard.on will add an event listener.
dashboard.on("tileClicked", function(event) {
    Log.log(event.detail);
});
```